# In java, I read that when instantiating a class, it is always always created on the heap. does that mean that the instantiated object is a reference?

Tags: java, c++

so lets say I want to instantiate an object person from a class Person in java. This is normally done by

```
Person person = new Person();
```

What is actually happening here? As far as I know, "new" calls the constructor of Person and also gives back an address from the heap to person that refers to the object person. If this is correct, then is person a reference to the object?

In c++ for example we can instantiate an object by

```
Person person();
```

How are these two different and what are the major implications the two methods.

Comment: In C++ `Person person();` is actually a *function declaration*.

Comment: And in Java it is a syntax error (unless it is in an `interface`).   Please correct the inaccuracies in your Question so that we can understand what you are *really* asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java objects are always created with `new`. Objects are always allocated on the heap, and what you receive is indeed a reference to this object. But unlike in C++ this heap is managed by the garbage collector, so you don't have to care about freeing memory.

In C++ objects can be allocated on the stack using this syntax:

```
Person person;
```

or on the heap using this syntax:

```
Person* person = new Person();
```

In the latter version you receive a pointer to the object. When you allocate an object on the heap in C++, you always have to free it:

```
delete person;
```

Therefore this approach is error prone, as early returns or exceptions can skip the `delete`. Whenever possible, objects should be allocated on the stack.
However there are some cases in which this is not possible, for example when allocating an array of elements with the length known only at runtime. In such cases it is best to encapsulate the calls to `new` and `delete` in the constructor and destructor of a class. This is what e. g. the std::vector class does.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, all instances of classes are references. However, this is not true for structs which are always values.

There are two ways to instantiate a class, and they both give you a reference to the class. The two are as follows in C++:

```
//Creates a reference to an instance that lives on the heap
Person *person = new Person(); 
//Creates a reference to an instance that lives on the stack
Person person = Person();
```

The second is equivalent to your example: `Person person();`. It is not valid in Java I don't think. I'm not a Java programmer so I'm not sure.

The main  difference between the stack and the heap in C++ is that managing the heap is up to the programmer. This is like using `malloc` in C. However, the stack is created and destroyed whenever you enter or leave a function - this is great because it means you don't have to worry about memory management. The heap is managed for you in Java, and I don't think there is any way to put variables on the stack.  The downside of the stack is that it gets destroyed when the program exits a function and so references can't be created inside a function and returned.

```
public Person& thisFunctionWorks(){
    Person *output = new Person();
    return *output;
}

public Person& thisFunctionDoesnt(){
    Person output();
    return output;
}
```

Comment: `Person person = new Person();` is usually **not** legal C++. It would be okay if `Person` has a constructor that takes a `Person*`, but that's quite rare. And, applying the obvious correction, `Person* person = new Person()` does **not** create a **reference**. `person` is a **pointer**. And, finally, `Person person = Person()` does not create a reference. It creates an object. In C++, "reference" has a specific meaning, and it doesn't apply to either of these examples. Further, neither of those last two examples "works".

Comment: I'll correct my answer - but references and pointers are the same thing under the hood. I was trying to avoid juggling the terms 'referece' and 'pointer' - in the scope of the question they really mean the same.

Comment: No, reference and pointer **do not** mean the same thing, under the hood or otherwise.

Comment: My understanding is that a reference is just an implicit pointer